# MVC LINQ Not recognised method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I've got a linq query extracting data from a table and I want to, being given a Date, convert it to week ( for example what week of the year it is ).

And the GetWeekofYear function:

```
 private int GetWeekOfYear(DateTime d)
 {
     var cal = System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Calendar;
     return cal.GetWeekOfYear(new DateTime(d.Year, d.Month, 1), System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, System.DayOfWeek.Sunday);
 }
```

In its current state, when I'm trying to test it ( using Postman / Fiddler ) I am getting the following error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32
>   GetWeekOfYear(System.DateTime)' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression

Comment: You need to materialize you query to memory first - `var query = (from booking ..... where .... ).ToList().Select(x => new QuestionaireDetailsDTO() { .... });`

Comment: I've solved it by setting a getter in the object, but I've got another question. How can I prevent serialization to json for some object property and only serialize it if I want to ? I've tried [IgnoreDataMember], but doesnt seem to do the trick as I want to. @StephenMuecke

Comment: You need to ask a new question with the relevant details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occurs because Linq2Sql can not translate the `GetWeekOfYear` method to SQL.

Try the following:

- select raw data instead into `QuestionaireDetailsDTO`

  ```
  select new QuestionaireDetailsDTO() {
      DepartureDate = transport.DepartureDate 
  };
  ```
- add a getter to `QuestionaireDetailsDTO` that does the calculation:

  ```
  public string Week => GetWeekOfYear(DepartureDate);
  ```

This way the conversion happens in memory instead of on the DB.

If the `GetWeekOfYear` method resides in a project that is not accessible by the consumer of the DTO, add a postprocessing step instead after you have selected the DTOs from the DB.

```
foreach (var result in query) {
     result.Week = GetWeekOfYear(result.DepartureDate);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using .AsEnumerable()

```
var query = from booking in context.BookingTables
                    join transport in context.TransportAllotments on booking.TransportAllotmentID equals transport.TransportAllotmentID
                    join passenger in context.Passengers on booking.BookingID equals passenger.BookingID
                    join result in context.QuestionaireResults on passenger.PassengerID equals result.PassengerID
                    join question in context.QuestionaireQuestions on result.QuestionaireQuestionID equals question.QuestionaireQuestionID
                    where transport.DepartureDate >= startDate && transport.DepartureDate <= endDate && booking.BookingID == id
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    select new QuestionaireDetailsDTO()
                    {
                        ID = booking.BookingID,
                        Date = transport.DepartureDate,
                        Question = question.QuestionText,
                        Week =  GetWeekOfYear(transport.DepartureDate) 

                    };
```

Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

As meintoined, this happents because LinqToSQL wasnt able to translate your method to SQL. 
I think that answer from @GeorgPatscheider is not a best because you shouldn't change your data objects because some specific mechanisms of data access layer. 
So, answer from @PhongDao is more cool, but him solution will download too many fields from database. You can change your code this way:

```
var query = from booking in context.BookingTables
        join transport in context.TransportAllotments on booking.TransportAllotmentID equals transport.TransportAllotmentID
        join passenger in context.Passengers on booking.BookingID equals passenger.BookingID
        join result in context.QuestionaireResults on passenger.PassengerID equals result.PassengerID
        join question in context.QuestionaireQuestions on result.QuestionaireQuestionID equals question.QuestionaireQuestionID
        where transport.DepartureDate >= startDate && transport.DepartureDate <= endDate && booking.BookingID == id
        // select only fields which we need
        select new
            {
                ID = booking.BookingID,
                Date = transport.DepartureDate,
                Question = question.QuestionText,
                DepartureDate = transport.DepartureDate
            }
        // retrieve data from DB
        .ToArray()
        // create items which you need
        .Select(x=>
        new QuestionaireDetailsDTO()
        {
            ID = x.ID,
            Date = x.Date,
            Question = x.Question,
            Week = GetWeekOfYear(x.DepartureDate)
        })
        // forming results
        .ToArray();
```

Comment: I've solved it by setting a getter in the object, but I've got another question.
How can I prevent serialization to json for some object property and only serialize it  if I want to ? I've tried [IgnoreDataMember], but doesnt seem to do the trick as I want to.

Comment: I think that it should be separate question.